# Issue with POST JSON

Tags: android, json, http-post

Im trying send JSON file an http POST request, with 1 int and 2 list[]. Server get my request, but json is empty always. Whats wrong with my code?? When I POST HashMap login+pass, it works good, but with json something wrong..

```
 try {
               JSONObject jsonParam = new JSONObject();
                jsonParam.put("categories_1", y);
               jsonParam.put("categories_1", x);
               jsonParam.put("price", 3000);

               url = new URL(adress);
            conn = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
            conn.setReadTimeout(15000);
            conn.setConnectTimeout(15000);
            conn.setRequestMethod("POST");
            conn.setDoInput(true);
            conn.setDoOutput(true);

            OutputStream os = conn.getOutputStream();
            BufferedWriter writer = new BufferedWriter(
                    new OutputStreamWriter(os, "UTF-8"));
               writer.write(jsonParam.toString());

            writer.flush();
            writer.close();
            os.close();
            int responseCode=conn.getResponseCode();

            if (responseCode == HttpsURLConnection.HTTP_OK) {

                String line = null;
                BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(conn.getInputStream()));
                while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {

                    buffer.append(line);
                }
                resultJson = buffer.toString();

                Log.d(LOG_TAG, "response - " + response);
                Log.d(LOG_TAG, "Good response - " + responseCode);
            }
            else {
                response="";
                Log.d(LOG_TAG, "bad responce - " + responseCode);

            }
```

Comment: could be useful to share here your server logs/code or the 'hashmap' request in order to receive a concrete answer.